# What WSDL should be given to 3rd party vendor?

Tags: integration, soap, wsdl

We plan to integrate our salesforce instance with a 3rd party vendor via SOAP/XML.

Which version of WSDL should be given in this instance ?.

I did some reading online and it looks like there are some differences between these two WSDLs.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004760&language=en_US

Enterprise WSDL is more strongly typed and the results are more predictable.

Does this mean that I should give Enterprise WSDL to this 3rd party vendor ?

Can someone let me know their inputs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on whether you want your integration to be loosely coupled  with your salesforce schema or tightly coupled .

With partner WSDL the flexibility will be that even if another field is added to the object schema or the Schema changes with little effort at the third party end ,they should be able to recompile or fix without need for regenerating the WSDL.

With Enterprise WSDL every time you add fields or make change in object schema you will regenerate the newer version of WSDL and hand off to third party.

If you are building a generic product to mash up with salesforce prefer partner over Enterprise while if you are very sure on mappings and schema Enterprise WSDL will be sufficient .